# Wagtail always uses default site for URLs

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am using the Django site framework with wagtail.
Wagtail correctly gives me the settings I specified for each site.
I as of now have 2 sites registered:

```
127.0.0.1
172.1.16.155
```

So, when I visit 127.0.0.1, I get all the site settings for 127.0.0.1, and vice versa.
The issue is, I have 172.1.16.155 as my default site. When I navigate to a URL from 127.0.0.1, (example: `127.0.0.1:8080/home/`) it will go to 172.1.16.1 (`172.1.16.155:8080/home/`), and the same thing the other way around if I set the default site to the loopback addr.

I have tried using both `page.full_url` and `page.url`, but to no avail.
I have tried adding `http://127.0.0.1` to the site settings (though I know this is incorrect), also to no avail.

I am using the same root for both sites.
This is a requirement for my project, as I require the same pages to be displayed no matter the domain, but the icons and such must differ on each domain. This works. It's just that the HTML contains anchor tags which lead me off the domain I am currently on.

Some possibly relevant Django settings:

```py
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env("SECRET_KEY",default="django-insecure-#=($lwdhz$drt5@h752_puh!y^5aqxh!bn($t_$^x(qd#1p5=e")

DEBUG = str(env("DEBUG", default="False")).lower() in ['true', '1', 't', 'y', 'yes', 'yeah', 'yup', 'certainly', 'uh-huh']

SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY = None

ALLOWED_HOSTS = env("DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS",default="127.0.0.1 localhost").split(" ")
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = env("CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS",default="http://127.0.0.1 http://localhost").split(" ")

# Search
# https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/topics/search/backends.html
WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKENDS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "wagtail.search.backends.database",
    }
}

# Base URL to use when referring to full URLs within the Wagtail admin backend -
# e.g. in notification emails. Don't include '/admin' or a trailing slash
WAGTAILADMIN_BASE_URL = env("WAGTAILADMIN_BASE_URL", "http://127.0.0.1:8080")
WAGTAIL_SITE_NAME = env("WAGTAIL_SITE_NAME", "flex")


# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "flex.apps.FlexConfig",
    "blog.apps.BlogConfig",
    'reviews.apps.ReviewsConfig',
    "contact.apps.ContactConfig",
    "search",

    'wagtail_color_panel',

    "site_settings.apps.SiteSettingsConfig",
    "wagtail.contrib.settings",


    "wagtail.contrib.forms",
    "wagtail.contrib.redirects",
    "wagtail.embeds",
    "wagtail.sites",
    "wagtail.users",
    "wagtail.snippets",
    "wagtail.documents",
    "wagtail.images",
    "wagtail.search",
    "wagtail.admin",
    "wagtail.contrib.modeladmin",
    'treemodeladmin',

    "wagtail",
    "modelcluster",
    "taggit",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
]

WAGTAILIMAGES_EXTENSIONS = ["gif", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "webp", "svg"]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "core.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "templates"),
        ],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                'wagtail.contrib.settings.context_processors.settings',
            ],
            "builtins": [
                "core.templatetags.core_tags",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

For debugging purposes I have added print statements to the wagtail get_url method, like so:

```
    def get_url(self, request=None, current_site=None):
        """
        Return the 'most appropriate' URL for referring to this page from the pages we serve,
        within the Wagtail backend and actual website templates;
        this is the local URL (starting with '/') if we're only running a single site
        (i.e. we know that whatever the current page is being served from, this link will be on the
        same domain), and the full URL (with domain) if not.
        Return None if the page is not routable.

        Accepts an optional but recommended ``request`` keyword argument that, if provided, will
        be used to cache site-level URL information (thereby avoiding repeated database / cache
        lookups) and, via the ``Site.find_for_request()`` function, determine whether a relative
        or full URL is most appropriate.
        """
        # ``current_site`` is purposefully undocumented, as one can simply pass the request and get
        # a relative URL based on ``Site.find_for_request()``. Nonetheless, support it here to avoid
        # copy/pasting the code to the ``relative_url`` method below.
        print("getting url")
        if current_site is None and request is not None:
            site = Site.find_for_request(request)
            current_site = site
            print("site", site)

        print("current_site", current_site) # None
        # print(current_site, request, request.get_host() if request is not None else None) # None None None
        url_parts = self.get_url_parts(request=request)

        print("url_parts", url_parts)
        ....
```

and inside find_for_request:

```
    @staticmethod
    def find_for_request(request):
        if request is None:
            return None
        if not hasattr(request, "_wagtail_site"):
            site = Site._find_for_request(request)
            setattr(request, "_wagtail_site", site)

        print("Site: from_request", request._wagtail_site)
        return request._wagtail_site
```

this provides me with the following terminal output:

```bash
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 08, 2023 - 15:10:33
Django version 4.2.1, using settings 'core.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8080/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

Site: from_request Localhost
Site: from_request Localhost
Site: from_request Localhost
Site: from_request Localhost
Site: from_request Localhost
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/autoschade/') # I AM NAGIVATING FROM 127.0.0.1
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/caravan-en-camperschade/')# I AM NAGIVATING FROM 127.0.0.1
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/ruitschade/')# I AM NAGIVATING FROM 127.0.0.1
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/banden/')# I AM NAGIVATING FROM 127.0.0.1
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/over-ons/')
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/duurzaamheid/')
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/abs-actueel/')
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/autoschade/')
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/ruitschade/')
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/caravan-en-camperschade/')
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/banden/')
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/')
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/opdrachtgevers/')
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/')
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/')
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/abs-actueel/')
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/caravan-en-camperschade/')
getting url
current_site None
url_parts (2, 'http://172.16.1.155:8080', '/ruitschade/')
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 26173
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /static/css/core.css HTTP/1.1" 200 6927
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 241729
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /static/js/bold-and-bright.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1395
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /static/js/core.js HTTP/1.1" 200 12097
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 80372
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /media/images/slide-01-home.scale-100.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 203911
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /media/images/Beckers_en_mulder_0000_BeckersMulder_W1C2171.scale-100.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 181518
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /media/images/Beckers_en_mulder_0015_BeckersMulder_W1C1873_c.scale-100.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 127941
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /media/images/anwb.width-200.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 6256
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /media/images/interpolis.width-200.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 7216
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /media/images/icon-caravan-500.scale-100.png HTTP/1.1" 200 64961
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /media/images/icon-ruitschade-500.scale-100.png HTTP/1.1" 200 54691
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /media/images/icon-autoschade-500.scale-100.png HTTP/1.1" 200 80444
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /media/images/icon-banden-500.scale-100.png HTTP/1.1" 200 68924
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /media/images/alphabet.width-200.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 5460
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /media/images/HEMA.width-200.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 1148
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /media/images/wave-pattern-2.original.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 747
Site: from_request Localhost
Site: from_request Localhost
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[08/Aug/2023 15:10:33] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 3472
```

Comment: What do you have set as the root page for the two sites? Are they pointing to the same page, or different? If different, is one an ancestor of the other?

Comment: They are pointing to the same page, yes. @gasman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `page.full_url` and `page.url` properties have no access to the current request object, so there's no way for them to give preference to the site you're currently accessing the page from.

Within template code, you should use [the `{% pageurl %}` template tag](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/topics/pages.html#page-urls) - this picks up the current request from the template context, allowing it to adjust the resulting URL accordingly. Elsewhere (such as within a `get_context` method), you can use [the `Page.get_url` method](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/topics/pages.html#obtaining-urls-for-page-instances) instead.

Comment: Perfect! It now uses relative paths for the pages. Would it be possible to make it always use absolute paths?

Comment: Yes, you can use `{% fullpageurl %}` instead.